# Is it possible change length of native documentum attributes of dm_document type?

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

Launching:

*ALTER TYPE dm_document MODIFY title string (1000);*

I get:

[image]

Is it possible to do these kind of things in some other manner?

Comment: of  course: create attribute custom_title :)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible.

You can only add a new attribute, in dm_document  itself or any child object